# Почему в Optional не срабатывает orElse(), orElseGet(), если объект null?

Tags: java, optional

```
AggregationDescription aggregationLevel = getAggregationDescriptionBYTerm(LEVEL_FIELD, null, null);
```

Есть функция:

```
private AggregationDescription getAggregationDescriptionBYTerm(String term, Optional<String> subTerm, Optional<String> script){

    AggregationDescription aggregationDescription = subTerm.map(term2 -> {
        if(script != null){
            return AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).field(term)
                    .subAggregationDescription(Arrays.asList(AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term2).field(term2)
                                    .script(script.get()).build())).build();
        }
         return AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).field(term)
                .subAggregationDescription(Arrays.asList(AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term2).field(term2)
                        .build())).build();
    }).orElseGet( () -> script.map(scrpt ->{
        return AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).script(scrpt).field(term).build();})
            .orElseGet(() -> AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).field(term).build()));

    return aggregationDescription;
}
```

она падает сразу с `NullPointException` на строчке:

```
AggregationDescription aggregationDescription = subTerm.map(term2 -> {
```

если 2-ой параметр `Optional` `String subTerm == null`.
Ожидал, что в этом случае будет выполнен код из `orElseGet()`, но этого не происходит

Comment: @insolor, всё верно, спасибо! Я просто ещё по дурости пытался null в Optional обернуть ))) Напишите в ответ - отмечу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы буквально передаете `null`, пустую ссылку. У `null` нет никаких методов от `Optional` (вообще никаких методов нет), попытка вызвать любой метод от `null` вызовет NPE. То что вы указали тип аргумента `Optional`, не означает, что туда можно безболезненно `null` передавать, и он автоматом превратится в `Optional`.

Либо не передавайте `null`, оборачивайте в `Optional` или передавайте явно `Optional.empty()`:

```
AggregationDescription aggregationLevel = getAggregationDescriptionBYTerm(LEVEL_FIELD,
    Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
```

или уже внутри функции заменяйте `null` на `Optional.empty()` (выглядит не очень хорошим вариантом):

```
if (subTerm == null) subTerm = Optional.empty();
if (script == null) script = Optional.empty();
```

или просто передавайте через параметры обычный `String`, а внутри уже оборачивайте в `Optional`:

```
private AggregationDescription getAggregationDescriptionBYTerm(String term, String subTerm, String script){
    Optional<String> optionalSubterm = Optional.ofNullable(subTerm);
    Optional<String> optionalScript = Optional.ofNullable(script);

    AggregationDescription aggregationDescription = optionalSubterm.map(term2 -> {
        if(script != null){
            return AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).field(term)
                    .subAggregationDescription(Arrays.asList(AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term2).field(term2)
                            .script(script).build())).build();
        }
        return AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).field(term)
                .subAggregationDescription(Arrays.asList(AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term2).field(term2)
                        .build())).build();
    }).orElseGet( () -> optionalScript.map(scrpt ->{
                return AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).script(scrpt).field(term).build();})
            .orElseGet(() -> AggregationDescription.builder().term("by_" + term).field(term).build()));

    return aggregationDescription;
}
```

Фрагмент начиная с `if(script != null){` по-хорошему стоило бы переделать на что-то вида

```
return optionalScript.map(script -> ...).orElseGet(...);
```